# On basic measure and integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $\int_{0}^{1}fg \text{ }d\mathbb{P}=0$, for all $f$ $\in$ $L^{\infty}([0,1],\mathbb{P})$ and $g$ be a fixed function in $L^{1}([0,1],\mathbb{P})$ and where $\mathbb{P}$ is a probability measure in $[0,1]$. Is it true $g=0$ almost everywhere?
Attempt: I was trying to use dominated convergence theorem to show $\int|g|^{2}\text{ }d\mathbb{P}=0$, just want to  find $f_{n}\rightarrow \overline{g}$ bounded sequence, that I can do using density of $L^{\infty}$ in $L^{1}$, but the problem is $f_{n}$ need not dominated by $L^{1}$ function for applying DCT.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se].
Can you please [edit] your post and write your attempts at solving the problem?
If your question is clear and focused on your specific difficulty and you show your effort in solving the problem, it's more likely to get good and helping answers. By the way, take the opportunity to take the [Tour], if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on 
[ask], on 
[formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help)
and on writing down equations using 
[LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes since the dual of $L^1$ is $L^{\infty}$

$T_g(f):=\int_0^1fg$ is a bounded linear functional  $T:L^{\infty} \to \Bbb{C}$

and $T_g(f)=0,\forall f \Longrightarrow g=0$

$|T_g(f)| \leq ||f||_{\infty}||g||_1$

Comment: Why is this linear functional bounded?

Comment: @Desperatemathematician... I edited my answer

Comment: $\|T_{g}\|=\|g\|$?

Comment: Yes it is..but the functional is bounded so that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Take $f=I_{g>0}$ to get  $\int_{g>0} gdP=0$. Similarly $\int_{g<0} gdP=0$. These give $\int |g|dP=0$ so $g=0$ almost everywhere w.r.t. $P$.